# How can I parse a mathematical function from user input in Perl?

Tags: perl, math

I wrote a tool for polar functions. It lists values from an input range like that:

```
0 Grad: (0 RAD|1 RES)  
20 Grad: (0.349065850398866 RAD|1.3639702342662 RES)  
40 Grad: (0.698131700797732 RAD|1.83909963117728 RES)  
60 Grad: (1.0471975511966 RAD|2.73205080756888 RES)  
80 Grad: (1.39626340159546 RAD|6.67128181961771 RES)  
100 Grad: (1.74532925199433 RAD|4.67128181961771 RES)  
120 Grad: (2.0943951023932 RAD|0.732050807568878 RES)  
140 Grad: (2.44346095279206 RAD|0.16090036882272 RES)  
160 Grad: (2.79252680319093 RAD|0.636029765733797 RES)  
180 Grad: (3.14159265358979 RAD|1 RES)
```

It is based of the function

```
 abs(1 + tan($_[0]));
```

How can I parse such a function from UserInput (Perl syntax) and assign it to a variable?

I want to avoid changing the Perl script; making the function dynamic instead of static.

Greets and thanks for reading.

EDIT:
sorry for quadrupelpost....

Thanks for the help, but the following snippet gives wrong values:

```
print("Eingabe: Funktion (phi = $t); PERL syntax!: > ");
$iFunktion = <STDIN>;
chop($iFunktion);

print("Eingabe: Grad Start: > ");
$iGradStart = <STDIN>; 
chop($iGradStart);

print("Eingabe: Grad End: > ");
$iGradEnd = <STDIN>; 
chop($iGradEnd);

print("Eingabe: Schrittweite: > ");
$iSchrittweite = <STDIN>; 
chop($iSchrittweite);

print("\nBerechne Funktion von $iGradStart bis $iGradEnd Grad mit einer Schrittweite von $iSchrittweite\n");


for ($i = $iGradStart; $i < $iGradEnd; $i = $i + $iSchrittweite)
{
    $flRad = &deg2rad($i);
    #$flResult = &Compute($flRad);
    $t = $i;
    $flResult = eval($iFunktion);
    print("$i Grad: ($flRad RAD|$flResult RES)  \n");
}
```

Input was abs(1 + tan($t));

---

(additional info, merged from follow-up)

```
print("Eingabe: Grad Start: > "); 
$iGradStart = <STDIN>; 
chop($iGradStart); 

print("Eingabe: Grad End: > "); 
$iGradEnd = <STDIN>; 
chop($iGradEnd); 

print("Eingabe: Schrittweite: > "); 
$iSchrittweite = <STDIN>; chop($iSchrittweite); 
print("\nfrom $iGradStart to $iGradEnd Grad with $iSchrittweite\n"); 
for ($i = $iGradStart; $i <= $iGradEnd; $i = $i + $iSchrittweite) 
{ 
  $flRad = &deg2rad($i); 
  $flResult = &Compute($flRad); 
  print("$i Grad: ($flRad RAD|$flResult RES) \n"); 
} 

sub Compute { return abs(1 + tan($_[0])); }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: a side remark: use chomp instead of chop: it is safer.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $t = $flRad instead of $t = $i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Math::Expression::Evaluator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::Expression::Evaluator) *almost* does what you want, except that has no `abs()` and no way to add user functions (callbacks.) It took me about five minutes to add some rudimentary support, thought.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Trig;
use Math::Expression::Evaluator;

my $expr = join ' ', @ARGV;
die "No expression provided" unless $expr;
my $m = Math::Expression::Evaluator->new;
# NOT in the distribution
$m->add_user_function('abs', sub { abs($_[0]) });
my $func = $m->parse($expr);
die "Cannot parse" unless $func;
for my $i (0 .. 10){
    my $rads = deg2rad($i);
    my $res = $func->val({x => $_});
    print("$i Grad: ($rads RAD|$res RES)  \n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the [`eval` statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).  It allows you to evaluate a string as Perl code.

For example, this code:

```
print "Function? ";
chomp($function = <STDIN>);

for ($i = 0;$i < 10;$i++) {
  print $i,"->",eval($function),"\n";
}
```

Gives this:

```
Function? $i * $i
0->0
1->1
2->4
3->9
4->16
5->25
6->36
7->49
8->64
9->81
```

As you're running user input as code, if someone other than use is using your script, you'll want to do something to sanitise user input.  You may also want to do a substitution so users could, for example, enter `x` instead of `$i` etc.  If you want to catch errors from `eval` check the `$@` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what else you have going on, I think I'd skip the parsing idea and have the users create a Perl library or subclass. They wrap their code in subroutine names and tell your script the library and the sub name. You might also combine that with a proper config file or command-line options.

Comment: so there is no option to do this?

Comment: There is nothing built into Perl to be a mathemathical parser. If that's the crux of your problem, you're using the wrong language. There are plenty of ways to get this done, including my suggestion.